# Getting file not found error when trying to load eel.js

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, eel

I'm currently writing a simple GUI in html/python using eel. Unfortunatly, although having directly copied it from the official tutorial, i get the error "GET file:///C:/eel.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" when I'm trying to load eel.js. My header looks somethong like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My eel GUI</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
    <script>
        eel.expose(my_function)
        function my_function(text) {
            console.log("Hello!")
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Thank you for your help.

My python file looks ike this:

```
import eel

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        eel.init("web")
        eel.start("main.html", block = False)
        eel.sleep(5)
```

Comment: What's your project structure look like? Did you put all front-end related to a single directory?

Comment: @LearningNoob i got my python file and a folder "web" in the same folder and in the  web folder I got my "main.html"

Comment: Can I also look at your python file

Comment: @LearningNoob added it =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @eel.expose on top of your **init** function. Something like this:

```
class GUI:
    @eel.expose
    def __init__(self):
        eel.init("web")
        eel.start("main.html", block=False)
        eel.sleep(5)

    def test_my_function(self):
        eel.my_function()


x = GUI()
x.test_my_function()
```